# Как сделать починить фон (из картинки)

Tags: html, css

Да уж, давно тут не появлялся.
Вообщем - у меня есть css фона:

```
.fon {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(/assets/mainbg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 80vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.fon:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(10, 10, 31, 0.7);
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```
<div class="fon"></fon>
```

но тут же проблема - картинка не встает на задний фон. Тут даже `z-index: -1000;` не помогает! Перепробовал куча вариантов и никак. Помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо

Comment: все отлично работает https://codepen.io/KatushaSan/pen/YzYbJdB, мб путь неправильный к картинке пишите, обычно в консоле можно увидеть, что картинка не найдена

Comment: Нет, я имею ввиду что ```<h1>``` не отображается на картинке, точнее уходит под нее, а я хочу чтобы наверху был текст

Comment: взгляните еще раз на песочницу, это вы имеете в виду, контент по верх картинки?

Comment: да (тут от 14 символов - не обращайте внимания на этот текст)